# How to achieve the effect of having count (id) > without group by

Tags: mysql

How can I select all `ids` from `table_1` and include entries where table two have both a `KR` and `BR` status? `group by table_1.id having count(table_1.id) > 1` will only include a single id for each entry, I need them both. `where in ('KR', 'BR')` will give me either or. So what I need to effectively have is `where entry exist in table_2 AND has an entry for BOTH KR and BR`

```
table_1

id |
===+
 1 |
===+
 2 | 
===+
 3 |
===+
```

`table_2` is related to `table_1` via `table_1_id`

```
table_2

id | table_1_id | status
===+============+=======
1  |      1     | KR
===+============+=======
2  |      1     | BR
===+============+=======
3  |      2     | KR
===+============+=======
4  |      3     | KR    
===+============+=======
5  |      3     | BR
===+============+=======
```

With the above example the output would be

```
t_1.id | t_2.id | t_2.status
=======+========+===========
 1     |   1    |  KR
=======+========+===========
 1     |   2    |  BR
=======+========+===========
 3     |   4    |  KR
=======+========+===========
 3     |   5    |  BR
=======+========+===========
```

In this result set, `table_1.id = 3` will be left out because it does not contain an entry for both statuses, how to achieve this?

Edit: I have also attempted `having group_concat(table_2.status) in ("KR, BR")` 
but still only one entry for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to skin this cat but How about this?

```
SELECT t_1.ID, t_2.id, t_2.status
FROM table_1 t_1
INNER JOIN table_2 t_2 ON t_1.id = t_2.table_1_id
WHERE t_1.ID IN (SELECT table_1_id FROM table_2 WHERE status = 'KR')
AND t_1.ID IN (SELECT table_1_id FROM table_2 WHERE status = 'BR')
```

That may give you more rows with other statuses so you may need to add this to the where clause:

```
AND t_2.status in ('KR', 'BR')
```

Comment: Yep, like that.  Delete my own answer.